# What plays are the Shakespeare quotes in Star Trek VI from?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-vi-undiscovered-country

There are a number of quotes in *Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country* that are from Shakespeare plays. The title is one, and is cited on screen:

> **Chancellor Gorkon:** I give you a toast: the undiscovered country. [The others look confused] The future.
>
> **Everyone:** [Raises glasses] The undiscovered country.
>
> **Spock:** *Hamlet*: Act Three, Scene One.
>
> **Gorkon:** You have not experienced Shakespeare until you have read him in the original Klingon.

There are many other Shakespeare quotes in the film, mostly from General Chang. What plays are they from?

Comment: You'll find some answers [here](http://bardfilm.blogspot.pt/2009/06/shakespeare-and-star-trek-complete.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I am constant as the northern star,

Julius Caesar Act 3 Scene 1 Page 4

> To be or not to be?

Hamlet Act 3 Scene 1

> The undiscovered country

The Tragedy of Hamlet Prince of Denmark Act 3 Scene 1

> Once more unto the breach, dear friends

Henry 5 Act 3 Scene 1

> Cry havoc, and let slip the Dogs of War

Julius Caesar Act 3, scene 1,

> Tickle us, do we not laugh? Prick us, do we not bleed? Wrong us, shall we not revenge?"

The merchant of Venice Act 3 Scene 1 Page 1

I hope I got them all. As Robin Williams once said...I shall get me hence and touch myself....Anon

Comment: Thanks for that! Your answer would be even better if you indicated who in the movie said each Shakespeare quote.

Comment: @Thunderforge: You asked for all the quotes in that movie. It was all General Chang in the Undiscovered Country.

Comment: I thought that there were others who quoted it too, like how Gorkon did it in my original quote, but it's been a while since I've seen the whole film.

Answer (score 0):

Spoken by Martia:
"I thought I would assume a pleasing shape."
Hamlet:  "The devil hath power to assume a pleasing shape."

All spoken by Chang:

"Parting is such sweet sorrow"
Romeo and Juliet

"Have we not heard the chimes at midnight?"
 Henry IV Part 2

"Let us sit upon the ground and tell sad stories of the death of kings"
Richard II

"Our revels now are ended"
The Tempest

"The game's afoot"
Henry V